# ASP.NET MVC AJAX value not displaying

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

View:

```
  function success(arg) {
        var obj = arg.get_response().get_object();                   
        if (obj.ErrorMessage === '') {
           var answer = document.createElement('div');
           answer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.Answer));
           document.getElementById('answers').appendChild(answer);
       } else {
          document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = obj.ErrorMessage;
       }
    }   

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrganizationMeta", "Organization", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success" })) { %>             

    <input type="submit" name="button<%=OrganizationMeta.vcr_MetaKey + Lang.int_LangId %>" value="Save" />
    <div id="errors"></div>
    <div id="answers"></div>

<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult EditOrganizationMeta(FormCollection collection)
{
   return Json(new { Answer = "Record Successfully Saved", ErrorMessages = "Title is required" });
}
```

The thing is that success method in the javascript is not getting the required parameters. It is printing undefined there. Is there a problem in javascript method OnSuccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, quick debug suggestion:

```
function success(arg) {
    alert(arg);
    var obj = arg.get_response().get_object();
    ...
```

This is a simple check to see if you are getting anything passed back to you in the query.

Second suggestion:

What does this actually render as, when you view the source of the page...

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrganizationMeta", 
    "Organization", new AjaxOptions { 
         HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success" })) ...
```

You are looking for the bit where it calls the function titled "success" - does it pass the data into the function? If you're still stuck, update your question with the rendered HTML output for the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function success() {
var url = '<%= Url.Action("EditOrganizationMeta", "Organization") %>';
           $.post(url, null, function(data) {
               alert(data["Answer"]);
           });
}
```

this works for me